# Can't append the last word from a text file to a list

Tags: python, word-count

I want to make a list of words contained in a text file. But my code prints all but the last word of the file. What am I doing wrong ?

```
def word_map(file):
    text = file.read()
    word = ""           # used as a temporary variable
    wordmap = []
    for letter in text:
        if letter != " ":
            word = word+letter
        else:
            wordmap.append(word)
            word = ""
    return set(wordmap)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When exiting the loop you are not appending the last word, just try this:

```
def word_map(file):
    text = file.read()
    word = ""           # used as a temporary variable
    wordmap = []
    for letter in text:
        if letter != " ":
            word = word+letter
        else:
            wordmap.append(word)
            word = ""
    wordmap.append(word)
    return set(wordmap)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `wordmap = text.split(" ")`

I hope this helped, good luck.

Comment: You have missed `set()` constructor

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a final :

```
wordmap.append(word)
```

Because if your text file does not end with a space, it won't be appended